# Make DropDownListFor of List<String>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to make a DropDownListFor in a Razor view, displaying data from a List of type String:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<String> catgs = new List<String>();

            return View(catgs);

}
```

I cant figure out how to receive a Model of type String in View and how to write the DropDownListFor.

Thanks.

Comment: A dropdownlist needs a property to bind to (the selected value) - e.g. `string SelectedItem)` and a collection (the options to display) -`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: I need the options to display to be IEnumerable<String>, can you help me with the syntax of dropdownlist ? Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for a "request" maybe? I think your saying on your browsers client-side you want to build a dropdown list, and you are trying to understand how you can access the data in your client-side?  And is it only STring type your having problem with, if success, can you point out what has worked so far? Give some idea to go on here. Can you please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate a dropdownlist, you need both a property to bind to and a collection property for the options to display.

Model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyModel model= new MyModel
    {
        Items = new SelectList(new string[]{ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Side note: If your want to pre-select an option, the set the value of `SelectedValue`, e.g. `SelectedValue = "Item 2"` will mean the 2 option will be selected.

View

```
@model MyModel
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, Model.Items, "-Please select-")
```